# columnar database

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse, database-performance

I have a sales database where I want to get customer details based on these categories selection.
I have around 15 categories and my customer database is 5 million records.
Each product may fall under more than one category.
I need to retrieve customer name based on the category selected.
Is it a better approach to put all these categories as columns or create separate table for product and category and then inner join?
I want in terms of performance which one is a better approach.

**Approach 1:**

[image: option1]
here 1 says that the product is under that category.

**Approach 2:**

[image: approach2]

Comment: Approach number 2 is better. It's expandable, if you get new categories in approach one, than you should change table structure. It's also proper in relational way. And you can get table from,approach 1 with the help of pivoting.

Comment: thanks gofr1. But my problem is performance.Joining 5 million records won't be a problem?

Comment: @aditya, no. SQL Server handles `JOIN` efficiently, especially with the proper index.

Comment: Just wanted to remind about proper indexes :)

Comment: Thanks gofr1 and Felix  So, what is the final conclusion? approach 1 or approach 2?

Comment: Second, and don't forget about indexes!

Comment: Are these table for transaction or ONLY for reporting purpose?

Comment: Only for reporting purpose @NeerajPrasadSharma

Answer (score 2):

Second Approach (`Approach 2`) is much better solution rather than creating single table because it is not necessary that every product may have all categories in approach one you are reserving space by creating separate columns even though category exist or not, and what if in future if one category is increased you will have to alter the current structure of the table and it will be tough task.

Yes Join will be bit slow but if you create index properly it will perform much better.